# if form.validate_on_submit(): is not functioning

Tags: python, flask

I am using a ubuntu system and my IDE is vscode.

My system is not checking the if statement and it is redirecting me again to the same page

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('/home'))
```

Here is my form.py file

```
import flask_wtf as wtf
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import *
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError


# class registration(FlaskForm):
#     username = StringField('username' ,validators=[DataRequired(), Length( min=2 , max=20 )])

#     email = StringField('email' , validators=[ DataRequired(),Email()])

#     password = PasswordField('password' , validators=[DataRequired()])

#     conform_password = PasswordField('conform password',validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])

#     submit = SubmitField('sign up')

class registration(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])

    conform_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class login(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username' ,validators=[DataRequired(), Length( min=20 , max=20 )])

    password = PasswordField('password' , validators=[DataRequired()])

    remember = BooleanField('remember me')

    submit = SubmitField('login')
```

here is my main file

```
#  . venv/bin/activate export FLASK_APP=happ
#  export FLASK_APP=happ 
#  flask run



from flask import Flask , render_template,flash,redirect,url_for
from forms import login,registration
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY']='d125a3ba77d4cd00d6fd48101b29553503'




candates = [
    {
        'name': 'abhinav',
        'age': 'ten',
        'height': 'six',
        'dress': 'jeans'
    },
    {
        'name': 'anudeep',
        'age': 'five',
        'height': 'four',
        'dress': 'jeans'
    }

]

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

    
@app.route('/login')
def slogin():
    form = login()
    return render_template('login.html' , title='login' , form=form)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = registration()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('/home'))
    return render_template('register.html' , title='register' , form=form)

# @app.route('/po')
# def poi():
#     return redirect(url_for('slogin'))








    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here is my html file for registration

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='stylesheet.css')}}">

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="login-page">
  <form methods="POST" action="/">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
   <div class="form">
     <form class="login-form">
       <legend>register</legend><br>
       {{ form.username(placeholder="name") }}<br>
       <ul>
         {% for errors in form.username.errors %}
            <li style="color: red;" >{{ error }}</li>
         {% endfor %}
       </ul>
      
       {{ form.email(placeholder="email") }}<br>
       <ul>
        {% for errors in form.email.errors %}
           <li style="color: red;" >{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
       {{ form.password(placeholder="password") }}<br>
       <ul>
        {% for errors in form.password.errors %}
           <li style="color: red;" >{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
       {{ form.conform_password(placeholder="conform password") }}<br>
       <ul>
        {% for errors in form.conform_password.errors %}
           <li style="color: red;" >{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
       {{ form.submit(class="button") }}
       <ul>
        {% for errors in form.submit.errors %}
           <li style="color: red;" >{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
       <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="{{ url_for('slogin') }}">Sign In</a></p>
      </form>
    </div>>
  </form>
</div>>
           
{% endblock body %}
```

I am referring to this code from a series https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: In your jinja forms your error loops are asking for errors in (i.e) form.password.error, but the variable in the <li> tag below says error with no s.

Comment: my code is running without errors

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return redirect(url_for("/home"))
```

to

```
return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

without the slash.

Comment: Try fixing those error-for loops too and make sure you have no errors.

Comment: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog

The tutorial has a repo here